# Rails 3.1 Deployment to JBoss 4.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jboss, jruby

When deploying a Rails 3.1 app on JRuby to JBoss, I'm having a jndi/jdbc connection issue.  The data source exists and connects fine

```
17:47:20,862 ERROR [STDERR] JNDI data source unavailable: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc not bound; trying straight JDBC
17:47:20,926 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] unable to create shared application instance
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: jdbc adapter requires driver class and url
    from C:/opt/jboss/jboss-4.2.2.GA-Virgin/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp1619261931370223075MyApp-exp.war/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.0/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:21:in `configure_connection'
    from C:/opt/jboss/jboss-4.2.2.GA-Virgin/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp1619261931370223075MyApp-exp.war/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.0/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:84:in `initialize'
    from C:/opt/jboss/jboss-4.2.2.GA-Virgin/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp1619261931370223075MyApp-exp.war/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.0/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from C:/opt/jboss/jboss-4.2.2.GA-Virgin/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp1619261931370223075MyApp-exp.war/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.0/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6:in `jdbc_connection'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
```

...

```
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ConnectionNotEstablished) jdbc adapter requires driver class and url
17:47:23,010 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MyApp]] Error: application initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: unable to create shared application instance
    at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.init(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:39)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3856)
```

Database.yml

```
###############################################################
#################### PRODUCTION DATA ##########################
###############################################################

production:
  adapter: jdbc
  jndi: java:jdbc/my_datasource
  driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I've checked both the datasource and the Database.yml file but I have no clue why Rails is not finding the datasource.

**Update**

```
Warbler config

# Disable Rake-environment-task framework detection by uncommenting/setting to false
# Warbler.framework_detection = false
# 
puts 'Compiling the asset manifests & other files in the pipeline to the disk'
system('bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile')

# Warbler web application assembly configuration file
Warbler::Config.new do |config|

  # Application directories to be included in the webapp.
  config.dirs = %w(app config lib log vendor tmp)

  # Name of the archive (without the extension). Defaults to the basename
  # of the project directory.
  config.jar_name = "MyApp"

  # Control the pool of Rails runtimes. Leaving unspecified means
  # the pool will grow as needed to service requests. It is recommended
  # that you fix these values when running a production server!
  config.webxml.jruby.min.runtimes = 1
  config.webxml.jruby.max.runtimes = 1

  # JNDI data source name
  # config.webxml.jndi = 'jdbc/rails'
end
```

Datasource config

```
<datasources>    
 <xa-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/my_datasource</jndi-name>
    <track-connection-by-tx/>
    <isSameRM-override-value>false</isSameRM-override-value>
    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">myserver</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">mydb</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="SelectMethod">cursor</xa-datasource-property>
    <valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</valid-connection-sql>
    <user-name>user</user-name>
    <password>pwd</password>
      <metadata>
         <type-mapping>MS SQLSERVER2000</type-mapping>
      </metadata>
  </xa-datasource>   
</datasources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me when deploying a `.war` file warbled up for Rails 3.0.x / JBoss 5.1.0GA.

Assuming that you have successfully deployed your datasource with an XML configuration file that would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>my_datasource</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>MYDATASOURCE_URL</connection-url>
        <driver-class>your.Driver</driver-class>
        ... define any other connection properties here ...
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

You should confirm that your datasource is indeed up and running in your JBoss admin console.

Then, assuming you have the following in your `config/warble.rb` file:

```
# JNDI data source name
config.webxml.jndi = 'jdbc/my_datasource'

# JBoss web-xmle file
config.includes = 'jboss-web.xml'
```

... and further assuming that you have a `jboss-web.xml` configuration file in directly under your Rails project folder, with the following:

```
<jboss-web>  
    <resource-ref>  
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/my_datasource</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:/my_datasource</jndi-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>  
    </resource-ref>  
</jboss-web>
```

... then you should be OK, afaik.

Could you perhaps post your `warble.rb`, datasource XML configuration file, and any JBoss web configuration parameters you are setting?

**[EDIT]**
@Jared thanks for posting your configuration files. Off the top of my head, I can offer you the following bits of advice:

1. Correct the `jndi` value in your `database.yml` to `java:comp/env/jdbc/my_datasource`.
2. Define a `config.webxml.jndi` configuration in your `warble.rb`, and set it to `jdbc/my_datasource`.
3. Also, define a reference to a new JBoss web.xml file in your `warble.rb` with `config.includes = jboss-web.xml`.
4. Create this new `jboss-web.xml` to map the JNDI name to the JBoss resource reference name. Based on the files you have shared, that would be something along the lines of what I have shown above. You would create this file right under the root of your Rails project.

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: I will tomorrow.  Lightbulb went on tonight and I realized that the app might be loading before the datasources.  My coworker deployed just fine, but I was unable to (fresh JBoss, no other apps).  http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF210/Known+Issues+for+JBoss

Comment: added warble config, datasource, etc

Answer (score 2):

I took buruzaemon's advice.  Turns out however that I had accidentally copied my war file to the /deploy/uuid-key-generator.sar directory, I only discovered this after the jboss stack trace showed the wrong jruby-jars versions.

For what its worth, I learned to force the loading of datasource files before all applications by adding a dependency

```
<depends>jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=mydatasource</depends>
```

to

```
/jboss-web.deployer/META-INF/jboss-service.xml
```

Comment: thanks for sharing that bit on datasource loading dependency... good to know!